# RequireHTTPS on mvc2 .net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-3.5, http-redirect

Hey I'm using VS2008 so I can only work with MVC2. I'm trying to get all http requests to my site to switch to https. I added the [RequireHttps] to my controllers. All this seems to do is block any http requests and give an error page. I think in mvc 3 and 4 it has it so it just redirects it to https. Is this true?

What is the best way to redirect http to https for your website using mvc2? I read about [URL rewrite modules](http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html) but heard it's not secure in some articles like this [one](http://blog.michaelhidalgo.info/2013/09/redirecting-http-traffic-to-https-why.html).

Should I just use the URL Rewrite Module or is there a way to get [RequireHttps] in mvc2 to redirect to https? Or some other way?

Also I'll be using IIS 7.0

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.